# Best practices for pinned banner alerts in iPhone X view?

Tags: mobile, ios, notification, alerts

[image: iphoneX with pinned bottom alert]

Hey everybody,

I'm experimenting with pinning a full-width banner on an iOS app I'm working on, but as you can see it looks a little awkward with the bottom curvature of an iPhone X-12. I debated bumping it up slightly but then there would be a strange gap between the banner and the bottom of the screen. Is there a best solution for this scenario, or do full-width banners and iPhone X's just not mix?

(and FYI the app uses top navigation, not shown in the screenshot. And I did consider pinning the banner to the top but it was too disruptive and blocked out a lot of key info)

Thanks!

Comment: Looks fine to me. As long as the hitbox for that "X" is easily clickable I don't see any issues you need to resolve.

Answer (score 2):

Your screenshot doesn't show the home indicator. Your text and button is too close to the corner of the screen.

> Inset essential content to prevent clipping. In general, content should be centered and symmetrically inset so it looks great in any orientation, **isn’t clipped by rounded corners**, isn’t hidden by a sensor housing, and **isn’t obscured by the indicator for accessing the Home screen**.

https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/adaptivity-and-layout/, emphasis mine

I understand not wanting to have a ‘strange gap’, but really that gap is not strange at all and required for suitable use of the home indicator and obeying safe areas.

> Use matching insets when placing controls at the top and bottom of the screen, and leave ample space around the Home indicator so people don’t accidentally target it

https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/adaptivity-and-layout/

Your content should be present in the blue area indicated below, with only backgrounds extending to the bottom of the display.

> [image]

https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/adaptivity-and-layout/

This is standard practice for tab bars and toolbars — your bottom content should stop above the home indicator, and only its background material can extend beyond the safe area.

> [image]

https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/bars/toolbars/

Therefore the end result should look something like this, with a distinct unclipped area for tapping the close button.

[image]